# Angular Selecting and Copying a Text

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to enable a user to select a paragraph and copy it when he/she clicks a button. Currently, my code is like this, but it doesn't select the text nor copy it. I tried to import directives but it gave errors during the import process so, I went with the method below. What is wrong with my code?

HTML:

```html
<p>
  <span
    id="sticker"
    contenteditable
    [textContent]="_stickerData?.StickerData"
    (input)="onStickerDataChange($event.target.innerHTML)"
  >
    {{_stickerData?.StickerData}}
  </span>
</p>
<button
  mat-button
  id="btnCopy"
  matRipple
  class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12"
  (click)="copyText()"
>
  Copy
</button>
```

TS:

```
copyText() {
  const sticker = document.getElementById("sticker");
  const btnCopy = document.getElementById("btnCopy");

  btnCopy.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector("sticker");
    document.execCommand("copy");
  };
  this._messages.Show("Copied", "SUCCESS", 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, change your code to this:

```js
copyText(value: string) {
    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
    selBox.style.left = '0';
    selBox.style.top = '0';
    selBox.style.opacity = '0';
    selBox.value = value;
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox.focus();
    selBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox);

    this._messages.Show("Copied", "SUCCESS", 3);
}
```

and the html need to change a little with it:

```html
 <button mat-button id="btnCopy" matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="copyText(_stickerData?.StickerData)">Copy</button>
```

I think that it will work in your case :D

What does this function do? Simple: it creates an invisible textarea, copy the value and destroy it after all

Comment: Hello, thank you but when I paste it, it pastes "undefined". It doesn't paste the text I want to select.

Comment: I'll put the html as well, wait a moment :x

Comment: Done, see if it will help you

Comment: If it still prints undefined, you need to define the correct variable on html where I changed

Comment: You are as well :D